# Call all subclass methods from super?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm currently implementing some unit tests for my company's build scripts. To eliminate bloat and make it a little easier to implement new tests, I'm making all my test classes inherit from a custom subclass called `BasicTest` that inherits from PyUnit's TestCase.

There are currently two functions that all tests utilize from `BasicTest`: The constructor (Although it could obviously be overwritten in the future) and the `runTest()` method that is the default method name that the super's constructor uses if no value is passed in (e.g. `BasicTest()` would create a test that will execute the `runTest()` method when called upon, whereas `BasicTest('Foo')` would use the `Foo()` method).

I would like to make `runTest()` simply run all possible tests from the inheriting object it is called on. However, as `runTest()` is defined only in `BasicTest` and inherited by the subclasses, I'm looking for a way to dynamically call all of the subclass' methods from the super. I know this violates the rules of OO programming, but from what I can see, Python was never one to follow rules in the first place :)

For clarity, the following illustrates my intentions:

I want `runTest()` to be called from a subclass object and only handle that object's methods. Let's say `SubclassTest()` that has methods `TestParse()` and `TestExec()`. I want it so that:

```
sub = SubClassTest() 
sub.runTest()
```

runs `TestParse()` and `TestExec()`, but I want the `runTest()` method to be defined in and inherited from `BasicTest` without being overriden.

Comment: I can propose You to use `metaclasses` or `__subclasses__()`. What would You like more

Comment: Write an example and what you'd like to do. I don't see why you dont simply run runTest on the subclasses.

Comment: To Oleg: `__subclasses__()` sounds more reliable. Let's go with that :D

Jochen: As of right now runTest is not defined, it is simply the default string that TestCase uses as a specifier if no argument is passed. It does not _need_ to be implemented for a subclass of TestCase to function, but if it is not implemented a string must always be passed into the constructor to specify a method to take its place.

What I'm looking for is help implementing the runTest function in the BasicTest class that is a super to all my other test cases.

Comment: metaclasses are good if You need to collect only defined methods (not inherrited)

Comment: Oh, well in that case I'll look into metaclasses

Answer (score 3):

one can create metaclass which will collect all interesting methods of subclasses into class property

```
class TestMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        own_tests = [v for k,v in attrs.iteritems() if k.startswith('test')]
        attrs['test_method_list'] = own_tests
        return super(TestMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

set this metaclass to base class as `__metaclass__`
and implement `runTests` method

```
class BaseTest():
    test_method_list = []
    __metaclass__ = TestMetaclass
    def runTests(self):
        for method in self.test_method_list:
            method(self)
```

And after this all subclasses will be constructed using this metaclass

```
class TestOne(BaseTest):
    def test_foo(self):
        pass
```

In the end one can use collected methods running `runTests()` method

```
TestOne().runTests()
```

Comment: Correct me if my understanding is wrong, but it seems that the goal of this is to collect the methods of ALL subclasses that inherit from `BasicTest`.

If this is the case, I should clarify: I want `runTest()` to be called from a subclass object and only handle that object's methods.

As an example, let's say `SubclassTest()` that has methods `TestParse()` and `TestExec()`. I want it so that:

    `sub = SubClassTest()
    sub.runTest()`

runs `TestParse()` and `TestExec()`, but I want the `runTest()` method to be inherited from `BasicTest` without being overriden.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:
load base class .py file as module
and inspect

```
import inspect
import imp
imp.load_source((name of class by which to want that module), (path base class name of file).py)
module = __import__((name of class by which to want that module))

inspect.getmembers(module) will give you dict of name, cls
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help my current issue as it requires that I know the names of the subclasses and the modules they're stored in beforehand (All of these classes and the BasicTest super will be condensed into a single module using a setup script)

Comment: may be this can help ... put all your subclasses in a defined folder and glob it using `python glob`  ... make function which iterates through each and import it one by one then you can go for this check ... just a tweak ... hope it helps ..